# Current position in regex replacement expression

Tags: regex, perl

In a Perl regex with a replacement expression (`/e` modifier), I'm trying to find the position of the current match. The `pos` function seems to do what I mean. The following code

```
my $string = "Hello world!";
$string =~ s/world/"$& (found at " . pos($string) . ")"/ge;
print "$string\n";
```

prints

```
Hello world (found at 6)!
```

But I couldn't find where this is specified in the docs. The [documentation of `pos`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html) only says that it returns "the offset of where the last `m//g` search left off". So I'm not sure whether I can rely on this behavior.

Questions: Is this usage of `pos` documented anywhere? Can I rely on `pos` behaving this way under different Perl versions? Is there a better way to get the position of the current match?

Comment: Check out `@-` and `@+` to get match offsets: [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@LAST_MATCH_START)

Comment: *"I'm not sure whether I can rely on this behavior"* I don't understand. The documentation says that's what it does, so that's at least what it's supposed to do, and probably what it does do!

Comment: @Borodin In the case of a regex being executed, the documentation seems unclear to me. For example, "where the last m//g search left off" could mean the end position of the match as well.

Comment: @nwellnhof: Ah I see. It *does* mean the end position of the match. It's where the next `m//g` should start searching

Comment: @Borodin Of course, this is not an `m//g` … it's an `s///g` … documentation could be clearer. ;-)  (Although to be fair, the docs later imply that `pos()` is also set on `s///g`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@-` and `@+` variables to determine the start/end position of every capturing group as well as of the whole match.

- `@-[0]` will contain the *start* position of the entire pattern. It would be `6` in your example.
- `@+[0]` will contain the *end* position of the entire pattern. It would be `11` in your example.

---

Here's your example with `$-[0]`:

```
my $string = "Hello world!";
$string =~ s/world/"$& (found at " . $-[0] . ")"/ge;
print "$string\n";
```

It prints

> Hello world (found at 6)!

Comment: Thanks. For the record, the "English" name of these variables is `@LAST_MATCH_START`and `@LAST_MATCH_END` and they're documented in the [`perlvar`man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions).

Comment: It's important to note that `@-` and `@+` are updated after every *successful* regex pattern match, just like the capture variables `$1`, `$2`, ... The value returned by `pos` changes only after any *global* match, whether successful or not.

Comment: @nwellnhof: Remember that it may be simpler for you to `use English`, but anyone else who reads your code will probably have to go to [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to find out what your long, loud names mean in normal terms!

Comment: @Borodin On my system, the value returned by `pos` does change and always equals `$-[0]`.

Comment: @nwellnhof: That's hard to believe. If anything, `pos()` will be the same as `$+[0]`. Try `perl -MData::Dumper -E'for ("abc") { /b/; print Dumper( $-[0], $+[0], pos() ) }'` and then change `/b/` to `/b/g`